# Android: How to create a custom camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to create a custom camera, without using the default camera provided by android. I don't want to call intent in the doing the above process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Surface View](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-use-android-camera-to-take.html).

**Camera Integration with Surface View provide you a way to take photo in android application. You can Intent Activity for taking photo. But Surface View provide a way to take photo in Customization way. This article address about SurfaceView and Android Phone camera integration**

Comment: Can you please provide another link of the solution, if any.